# Building Hello World Gstreamer 1.2.3 Application in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gstreamer

I downloaded and installed Gstreamer 1.2.3 from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/ , created new project on Visual Studio 2012 and added hello world code from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html#section-helloworld .
However I can't build this application because I don't know how to add Gstreamer framework dependancy to my Visual Studio solution. I tried Gstreamer 0.1 Visual studio tutorial http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows and it worked fine with 0.1 version and it's basic project, however I'm unable to take similar steps on 1.2.3 version because this newer version of gstreamer has different file organization and I just can't find the same files.
How can I setup my visual studio environment which would let me to build gstreamer projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to download and install both gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.2.3.msi and gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.2.3.msi from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.3/ .
The configuration process is similar to 0.1 version configuration process. Oh, by the way, in Visual studio "properties->configuration properties->debugging" working directory needs to be set to $(GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86)\bin

Comment: Where do you verify the GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86 is setup by default ?

Comment: @YumYumYum GSTREAMER_1_0_ROOT_X86 is environment variable. Other Gstreamer versions may have different environment variable.